# How do I pass varaibles to another python file

Tags: python, shell

I have two files and needed to move a variable from one to the other. There is also some shell scripting involved.
For example, I have script1.py and a variable called var1.

```
script1.py

var1 = sys.argv[1]
```

When I try to import this into another Python file. For e.g.

```
script2.py

from script1.py import var1
print(var1)
```

It is actually running the sys.argv[1] again in script2.py. This is how my shell script looks.

```
shellcode.sh 
python3 script1.py "1st parameter"
python3 script2.py "2nd"
```

How to get only the "1st parameter" not "2nd".
I'm a complete beginner at python and shell scripting. Is it related to pass by value? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since there are 2 completely separated Python processes running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this would be to use the parameter as a variable in your shell script and just pass both to the second python argument.

shellcode.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PAR1="1st paramter"
PAR2="2nd parmaeter"
python3 script1.py $PAR1
python3 script2.py $PAR1 $PAR2
```

Otherwise you could write and read the argument something like

script1.py:

```
import sys
var1 = sys.argv[1]
with open('script1_var.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(var1)
```

script2.py:

```
import sys
with open('script1_var.txt', 'r') as f:
    var1 = f.readlines()[0].strip()
var2 = sys.argv[1]
print('var1', var1)
print('var2', var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

pass directly arguments from `script2.py` it should work.

script1.py

```
import sys
var1 = sys.argv[1]
```

in script2.py

```
from script1 import var1
print(var1)
```

on shell run like this

```
python3 script2.py --test
```

Will print #

```
test
```